# Least number of marked symbols

Tags: optimization, logic-grid

I have a 7x7 grid, where I want to find the least amount of "marked positions" so a group of non-marked positions aren't bigger then 4 (only moving up, down, left and right and not diagonal). Below is an example with a solution of using 19 marked symbols.

[image]

Can anyone come up with a solution using only 18 or less?

Comment: [Similar question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90126/8x8-grid-with-no-unpainted-pentominoes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect this to be an optimal solution, but have no proof of that yet.

> It has just 17 marked squares.
>
> ```
>  . X . . . X .
>  . . X . X . .
>  . X . X . X .
>  X . . X . . X
>  . X . X . X .
>  . . X . X . .
>  . X . . . X .
> ```

Comment: Beat me to it! (as usual)

Comment: That looks like an optimal solution indeed since all groups have 4. Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this set covering problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each pentomino $p$, let $C_p$ be the set of (five) grid cells that comprise it.  For each grid cell $(i,j)$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether that cell is marked.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to linear constraints:
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in C_p} x_{i,j} \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $p$}$$
The optimal values for $n\in\{1,\dots,10\}$ are
\begin{matrix}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
\min & 0 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 17 & 24 & 31 & 39 \\
\end{matrix}