# Ten tetrominoes inside an 8x8 grid

Tags: mathematics, geometry, polyomino, packing

Can you place ten [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) inside an 8x8 grid, such that they do not overlap or touch each other orthogonally (horizontally or vertically) ?

Comment: Another way of articulating this is to find an 8 x 8 pixel binary image for which performing [_connected-component labelling_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) results in exactly 10 components of area 4.

Comment: ok I'll wait then. But I can't give the tick to all 3...

Comment: The solution already existed on the site https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90126/8x8-grid-with-no-unpainted-pentominoes/90142#90142

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As promised, here are the three solutions that my computer found.

The first was already found by [franck vivien](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/116616/20814) (and Bass), the second by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/116623/20814).

> [image]

Answer (score 12):

what about the following arrangement of

> 8 T tetrominoes + 2 squares?
>  [image: 10 tetrominoes in a 8x8 grid]

I found it manually by searching arrangement of same pieces, then had to change a bit strategy

Comment: Well done! Can you find any other solutions?

Comment: I have confirmed by computer that there are two other solutions (ignoring rotation/reflection). If no one finds these, I'll post them in a day or two.

Comment: @JLee You are talking about the *independent domination number*.  You might be interested in [my answer to this closely related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496306/minimal-covering-of-a-5-times-5-square-with-t-shaped-tetrominoes/3496364#3496364).

Comment: @Jlee It's fundamentally the same problem, just on a different graph.  For $n\in\{1,\dots,8\}$, the optimal values are $0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4$.

Comment: @JLee To see that $4$ is a lower bound for the independent domination number, note that no two of the following four tetrominoes can be blocked by a single tetromino:
$$\begin{matrix}
1 &. &. &. &. &2 &2 &2 \\
1 &1 &. &. &. &. &2 &. \\
1 &. &. &. &. &. &. &. \\
. &. &. &. &. &. &. &. \\
. &. &. &. &. &. &. &. \\
. &. &. &. &. &. &. &3 \\
. &4 &. &. &. &. &3 &3 \\
4 &4 &4 &. &. &. &. &3 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137076/discussion-between-jlee-and-robpratt).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis my brain hurts. Please post the 3rd solution so i can kick myself

Comment: @JLee I have now posted it

Answer (score 6):

Now that I realize we don't have to use only T's, here is one solution:

> [image: 1]

Comment: Well done. This is the original solution I had in mind. Now there is one more solution left. Can you find it?

Comment: I tried for about 3 hours. Gotta take a break. Thx for the fun puzzle.